# Kendo grid - pass to server only changed data

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, crud, remote-server, kendo-datasource

Is it possible to configure a parameterMap to send server only changed item, or only actual added ... not all models?

I found the function isNew() and dirty in kendo documentation for check if is model edited or if is it new, but it's not working for me.

Here is my code:

```
parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
        if (operation == "create" ) {
           for(var i = 0; i < options.models.length; i++) {
              console.log(options.models[i].isNew());
              //Uncaught TypeError: options.models[i].isNew is not a function
           }
        }
        if (operation == "update" ) {
           for(vari = 0; i < options.models.length; i++) {
              console.log(options.models[i].dirty);
              // never jump there
           }        
        }
        return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
    }
```

Similarly, I need declare destroy ... What is wrong?

Comment: pretty sure that is already the default behavior

Comment: actualy send all models .. so i don't have idea how separate edited model from others

Comment: what do you mean it sends all models?  on update?  create? read? delete? are you using inline editing? batch? popup?  you're describing functionality that i've never seen using kendo so i'm not sure at what point you're receiving all models

Comment: for example ... i click add new record, fill inputs and after confirm send all models from datasource in one array ... so i couldnt check which is my new added or edited

Comment: it will usually look at the "id" field to see if it has an actual value.. if not, it thinks that the record is new.. can you show the rest of your grid markup?

Comment: https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2016/06/23/hFnx.png
here is create ... you were right with models without ID, but during update have id all models, and here is problem